# How to turn a Photoshop script (Javascript) into a plug-in / program with a UI

Tags: javascript, plugins, interface, photoshop, photoshop-script

I'm not a developer so I'm not sure how to properly phrase my question.

As a graphic designer I work a lot on sorting through and processing batches of images through Photoshop to meet specific specs. I wrote/hacked together a short script (Javascript) that runs through Photoshop to accomplish the sorting part of this task.

Rather than opening the javascript file every time, is there a way I can turn it into a little standalone programme or Photoshop plug-in? I want people to be able to see a simple interface of some kind where they can choose certain options (like which folder to run the script on), and then just click "GO".

I'm not sure where to start so even just some links to resources would be great.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? You want to run the script without having Photoshop open? That would not be possible. How would you like the user to start the script?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options: a simple one and a difficult one.

- A simple one would be adding an interface to you script via [ScriptUI](https://creativepro.com/files/kahrel/indesign/scriptui.html): this way your script can show UI. You'll still need to run the script manually (you can assign it to a hotkey or use in an Action tough) and this is going to block PS UI
- A difficult one would be transforming your script to an [extension panel](https://github.com/Adobe-CEP/CEP-Resources/blob/master/CEP_8.x/Documentation/CEP%208.0%20HTML%20Extension%20Cookbook.md): an entity that consists of HTML+JS for UI and JSX for your host app (your script). This way you can have ui for your script always opened and use any your favourite js framework

Note that plugins in Photoshop terminology are compiled C++ entities: believe me you don't want to go that way